# What's wrong with this list comprehension (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Having problems with what should be a "no brainer" LC.

Code snippet below:

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range((end_date - start_date).days):
        yield start_date + dt.timedelta(n)


def get_workdays_between_dates(start_date, end_date):
    return [x in daterange(start_date, end_date) if x.date.weekday() in range(0,7)]
```

Python barfs a 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax error' when parsing function get_workdays_between_dates(). It looks ok to me though ...

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's `x`? :) Yes, that's an invalid syntax, you are missing the `for` part.

```
[x for x in daterange(start_date, end_date) if x.date.weekday() in range(0,7)]
```

Comment: Gah!. Going away to stand in the corner now. So ashamed of myself :)

Comment: Pick a sunny corner with cocktail umbrellas

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the syntax error, you have THREE more problems in that line. Given that `x` appears to refer to a `datetime` object:

Problem 1: `x.date` is a method, not an attribute

```
>>> import datetime
>>> x = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> x
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 19, 9, 23, 53, 136000)
>>> x.date.weekday()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'weekday'
>>> x.date()
datetime.date(2012, 2, 19)
>>> x.date().weekday()
6
```

Problem 2: `.date` is redundant

```
>>> x.weekday()
6
```

Problem 3: It seems to me that `x.weekday() in range(0,7)` would always be `True`. Perhaps you mean:

```
# initialisation
NON_WEEKEND_DAYS = set(range(0, 5))

# as needed
... x.weekday() in NON_WEEKEND_DAYS ...
```